# A c++ program to take the size and components of an Array from user and return the reversed Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written this code that should take the size and components of the array from the user and then return the reverse of the Array but not able to identify and fix the error.
My best guess is that the while loop is causing trouble, but I am not sure.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


// function to reverse given array
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int end){

while (start<=end){
    int temp = arr[start];
    arr[start] = arr[end];
    arr[end] = temp;
    start++;
    end--;
       
}

}


// function to print given array
void printArray(int arr[], int size){
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   cout << arr[i] << " ";
}


int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int mainarray[] = {n} ; 
    n = sizeof(mainarray);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> mainarray[i];
    }

reverseArray(mainarray , 0, n-1);
printArray(mainarray ,n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: variable length arrays are not a standard feature of C++, and even when compiler vendors offer them by extension, that isn't the way to declare them. `int mainarray[] = {n};` declares an `int` array of **one** integer. And `sizeof` usage is also wrong, returning the number of bytes, not integers, in said-same array. You already have `n`. Computing with `sizeof` is both redundant and error prone (obviously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int mainarray[] = {n} ; 
n = sizeof(mainarray);
```

This is a wrong way to allocate array with `n` elements. This is allocating an array with one element, then overwriting `n` with the number of bytes taken by the array.

Instead of this, you should do this for allocation:

```
int* mainarray = new int[n];
```

Then, before `return 0;`, you should cleanup this by doing:

```
delete[] mainarray;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked but please clear this doubt of mine:-

 int* mainarray = new int[n];     //pointer mainarray now stores the location of our array new int[n] and whenever we call mainarray in our funtions, the content in required location of new int[] is affected.
Am i right?
But i still did not understand the purpose of  delete[] mainarray;
Kindly explain or share a link of material where it is explained.
That would be great.